# Shell scripting modification help required

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu-18.04

I have this inside my `module1.sh` script, but I get errors failed input errors when trying to run it via cronjob. That's because *\n1\n1\n1\n1000\n5000\n10\n1* is inputting the information wrong, but I don't know how else to accomplish: press 1 then Enter.

```
cd /home/cbt/module1.sh
printf '\n1\n1\n1\n1000\n5000\n10\n1' | ./module1.sh
./module1.sh << EOF

1
2
3
EOF
```

Comment: You could use `expect` or just change `module1.sh` so that it reads arguments from the command line. By the way, why are you changing directory into a file on line 1?

Comment: It makes no sense for you to have what is displayed in the question in `module1.sh`.  You are showing how you call it?  Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].